# In python, to consider the image files based on their names for computing

Tags: python-3.x, string, file

i have 60000+ images in one folder and i want to include files based on their names in computing values.
I am giving the parameter as "year" and my image file names are like

```
year = '2015'
170519-1-27-1 represents 2017
161022-1-31-1 represents 2016
150926-1-27-1 represents 2015
140821-1-65-1 represents 2014
121011-4-39-1 represents 2012
090714-2-36-1 represents 2009
```

For example if the year is "2015" I want to include files uptill 2014 and exclude (only exclude not to delete/remove) 2015 , 2016 and 2017 files for computing some values.

How do I do that ?
Here the code which i tried:

```
year = '2015'
for oimg in sorted(glob.glob(inputdir + '*.jpg')):
            
            img_path = oimg.split('/')[-1]
            imgstr = img_path.split('.')[0]
            
            if imgstr[:2] < year[2:4]:
               continue
            print(imgstr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the last 4 characters of the filename, cast it to a int and check if it is less than or equal to `int(year)`.

Comment: How to exclude those files while comptuing?

Comment: Can you post the code you use for computing? If it's a loop, you can just skip iterations.

Comment: I did what you have suggested but how to skip iterations.

Comment: You can do `if imgstr[:2] > year[2:4]: continue`. This will skip to the next iteration if the condition is true. Outside the if statement you can have the rest of the computation for when imgstr[:2] <= year[2:4].

Comment: I did but for year="2015" it also considers uptill 2015. I do not need 2015. I have edited , it prints 2015 data too.

Comment: I got it it shoul be  `if imgstr[:2] >= year[2:4]: continue`